# Running Emacs commands from ansi-term in character mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to have the ability in Emacs to trigger the standard behavior associated with `M-x command RET` in **character mode** on an **ansi-term** buffer.

I actually used to have this functionality, but for some reason it went away in the last couple of days, even though I have **not** upgraded Emacs (although I may have inadvertently modified my init file)

Also, I have the following hook that used to work (to switch between windows), but it doesn't anymore.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-J") 'windmove-left)          ; move to left window
(global-set-key (kbd "M-L") 'windmove-right)         ; move " " 
(global-set-key (kbd "M-I") 'windmove-up)            ; move " "
(global-set-key (kbd "M-K") 'windmove-down)          ; move " " 

(add-hook 'term-mode-hook
  (lambda()
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-J") 'windmove-left)  
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-L") 'windmove-right) 
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-I") 'windmove-up)    
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-K") 'windmove-down)  
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-F") 'toggle-maximize-buffer) 
    ))
```

### Update:

If I evaluate `(lookup-key term-raw-map (read-kbd-macro "\C-x"))` **prior** to opening any ansi-term, I get: `term-send-raw`, but if I evaluate it **after** I open an ansi-term, I get:

```
(keymap #^[nil nil keymap 
#^^[3 0 pop-global-mark nil list-buffers term-send-raw list-directory eval-last-sexp find-file nil nil indent-rigidly ...] #^^[1 0 #^^[2 0 
#^^[3 0 pop-global-mark nil list-buffers term-send-raw list-directory eval-last-sexp find-file nil nil indent-rigidly ...] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] (67108912 . text-scale-adjust) (67108925 . text-scale-adjust) (67108909 . text-scale-adjust) (67108907 . text-scale-adjust) (67108896 . pop-global-mark) (C-left . previous-buffer) (left . previous-buffer) (C-right . next-buffer) (right . next-buffer))
```

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, I have the same behavior. Maybe you shouldn't redefine `C-x C-b` for term-send-raw at all. For me it works by default: all my keybinds like `C-x C-d` work in term-char-mode without  any additional settings. I redefine keybinds like `M-s` or `C-p` only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use such setting:

```
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-x") 'nil)
```

then `M-x` works in `term-char-mode` as usual. If you use global keybinds for some functions, put `'nil` for same keybinds in `term-raw-map`.

Comment: Thanks artscan. This works great! I'm impressed. Would you mind elaborating on why setting `M-x` on the `term-raw-map` keymap to `nil` enables the global key bindings? I could not find much on this in the documentation. What is the meaning of `nil` in this context?

Comment: For some odd reason, this is not working for me for `C-x C-b`.  I have `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'helm-buffers-list)` in my `.emacs` file, and I would like to call helm-buffers-list from within `ansi-term` in character mode. If I add `(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-x C-b") 'nil)` I get: `"Key sequence C-x C-b starts with non-prefix key C-x"`

Comment: In my setup (see `(lookup-key term-raw-map (read-kbd-macro "\C-x"))` ) `C-x` is binded to **keymap** and `(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-x C-b") 'nil)` works normally. Maybe in your setup `C-x` is binded to something else?

Comment: It's really odd. Once I have an ansi-term open, I can call `C-x C-e` `(eval-last-sexp)` on `(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-x C-b") 'nil)`, and this fixes the problem... **BUT** it wont work inside the hook... (or anywhere else I put it in my init file)

Comment: I have added an update to my OP with more info about the keymap associated with `C-x`.